# Azure DSC VM Extension: Why does $Home directory change?

Tags: powershell, azure, agent, dsc

Environment: PowerShell Version: 5, Windows Server 2016

My DSC creates a Hello World file in the directory:

```
$Home\Desktop
```

Which I expected to map to `C:\Users\<username>\Desktop`.  And invoking `$home.desktop` on the remote VM's PowerShell will indeed return the Desktop directory.  But when the DSC itself is executed, the file is instead created in: `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop`.

Below is a copy of the DSC:

```
Configuration HelloWorldConfig 
{
    Import-DscResource –ModuleName 'PSDesiredStateConfiguration'
       Node localhost 
       {
              File TestFile {
                     Ensure = "Present"
                     DestinationPath = "$Home\Desktop\HelloWorld.txt"
                     Contents = "Hello World!"
              }

       }
}
```

Any idea why this is happening?  Perhaps the Azure VM Agent is its own user and therefore it's `$home` directory is not in `C:\Users`, but is rather `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Azure DSC Extension` is run by the `Azure VM Agent` which is running as `local system` and `C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\Desktop` is `local system`'s desktop.

Comment: What local system is: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684190(v=vs.85).aspx